# Replicate ++ operator via AutoHotKey script?

Tags: autohotkey

Let's say I'm programming in a text editor and want to iterate a variable:

```
i++
```

Now, let's say for whatever reason, this language doesn't `++` but rather:

```
i = i + 1
```

this is annoying when you are used to the first syntax. I want a script which when receiving `++` translates this to a series of commands I send (control shift left arrow, etc, this is not the part I'm having trouble with).

However I cannot seem to get this method to execute:

```
+ & +::

Msgbox test
return
```

For whatever reason though, this is not fully being called - I do not see the keystroke for `+` when typing so I know it is somehow getting to that method, but, not registering the second `+`.

How can I call a method using the keystrokes `++` as a trigger?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is very unclear to me. **(1)** The `++` operator does exist in AHK (at least `AHK_L`, but who uses basic...) **(2)** A key sequence followed by two colons (e.g. `!g::msgbox, text`) indicates a *hotkey label*, not a function (or *method*, as you call it) **(3)** Assuming *(2)*, the key sequence `+ & +` doesn't make very much sense. What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to build a hotkey? If yes, say when it should be triggered and what it's supposed to do. And what does the increment operator have to do with all this?

Comment: @MCL I clarified and realized it was really poorly written.

Comment: Could it be that you want to auto-replace `someVar++` with `someVar = someVar + 1`?

Comment: @MCL yes, third time's the charm... must be a rough Friday for me :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a really great library called [RegEx Powered Dynamic Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15015-regex-powered-dynamic-hotstrings/). And replacing `someVar++` with `someVar = someVar + 1` *reeks* of RegEx!

This one line will do what you want:

```
hotstrings("(\w+)\+\+", "%$1% = %$1% {+} 1")
```

This will work for every variable name that's alphanumeric (plus underscore): `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Of course, this won't work for every language since it strongly depends on the syntax. For example, some languages use `:=` to assign expressions, other languages need a semicolon to complete a statement and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Hotstrings WILL work for this occasion, however, you might need the "?" modifier for it to grab even within a "word" try it like this:

```
:*?:++::
    ClipboardOld := ClipboardAll,Clipboard := ""
    Send, +^{Left}^c
    Clipwait
    Send, ^{Right} = %Clipboard% {+} 1
    Clipboard := ClipboardOld,ClipboardOld := ""
return
```

This also preserves the clipboard.